# bmesh.ops holes_fill vs edgeloop_fill vs edgenet_fill

Tags: python, bmesh

Can anyone help me understand the difference between `bmesh.ops.holes_fill`, `bmesh.ops.edgeloop_fill` and `bmesh.ops.edgenet_fill`. The docs aren't clear, at least to me. I'm trying to add a cap on an open edge loop, eg on the end of a tube. Or if there is another operation I should use, that would help too. Trial and error is extremely difficult because they all seem to fail silently.